# Problem in assigning value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I already have the value of Agency Code. However, I can't put it back to Patient(AgencyLabel). How will I assign it to Patient(AgencyLabel)? I need this in order to for me retrieve the list of the Patient List.

Comment: Yes, your Agencycode property is read-only. You need: set

Comment: yes, i know but i cant put a set in my Agency code.. its a DLL

Comment: You need to contact the dll provider then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AgencyLabel oAgencyLabel = new AgencyLabel(itemChart.Agency.AgencyCode, null);
Patient oPatient = new Patient(oAgencyLabel, PatientCode);
```

Answer (score 4):

2 options:

- Use the constructor `public AgencyLabel(int AgencyCode, string AgencyName);` to create a new object
- Change the code in class `AgencyLabel`  to `public int AgencyCode { get; set; }`

**EDIT**
Just saw your comment under the question: since there's no way to change the code, you have to use the constructor with the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `AgencyCode` declaration to be the following:

```
public int AgencyCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: i can't change it bec. its a dll.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int AgencyCode { get; }
```

You only assign `get`, so it's read-only.
You should do `public int AgencyCode { get; set; }`

Comment: AgencyCode is a DLL.. so i cant modified the CMSAcess.. Is there any possible answer?